# Context-Free Grammars(Clarification on answer)

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to make sure if i did a) correct. I believe it makes sense, just trying to see if anyone has any suggestions.

The grammar

```
     G=<V,T,P,calculation>
```

for the calculator language  is defined by:

V={calculation, expression, value, number, unsigned, digit, sign, operator}
T={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,*,/,=,.}

P consists of the following productions (rules):

1. calculation -> expression =
2. expression -> value | value operator expression
3. value -> number | sign number
4. number -> unsigned | unsigned . unsigned
5. unsigned -> digit | digit unsigned
6. digit -> 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9
7. sign -> + | -
8. operator -> +| -| *| /

Show:

(a) 100/2.5=  is in the calculator language;

My answer:

a.

`<calculation>`

```
  => <expression> =
  => <value> <operator> <expression>  
  => <value> / <expression>
  => <number> / <expression>
  => <number> / <value>
  => <number> / <number>
  => <unsigned> / <unsigned . unsigned>
  => <digit><unsigned> / <digit . digit>
  => 1<digit><unsigned> / 2.5
  => 10<digit> / 2.5
  => 100 / 2.5
```

Comment: It's a correct derivation. If I were to be picky, then I would say that for consistence it should be `<unsigned> . <unsigned>` rather than `<unsigned . unsigned>`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, should i have kept "=" at the end of each line since  rule 1?

Comment: I would remove it because you have `=>` already. More importantly, if that detail is important for your TA, then I would change the group/course or even school if that's a prevalent attitude (although it may be justified if it is about readability in some concrete programming language, but it's not that case here).

Comment: Well logically speaking, '=' exists in the terminal symbols. So it can be used, and productions rule one states calculation simplifies to <expression> = .. and so on

Comment: I would definitely keep the "=" since rule 1, since a) the expression you are asked to find includes "=" and b) rule 1 specifically says that "=" is included. I would say that it is clearly wrong to omit it, and displays a lack of understanding of BNF notation.

Comment: Alright, I was exactly thinking that.. thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, @mrp is right.